# Generating sample proportions when the true proportion is close to 1

Tags: simulation, proportion

Suppose the true proportion of success is $\pi$.
I would like to generate sample proportions around $\pi$.

I can use

```
p.hat <- rnorm(n=10, mean=pi, sd=sqrt(pi * (1 - pi) / n))
```

The problem is that values > 1 are generated when $\pi$ is close to 1.

I have thought that I can use a logit transformation

```
mu <- log(pi / (1 - pi))
```

and then use

```
mu.hat <- rnorm(n=10, mean=mu, sd=???)
pi.hat <- exp(mu.hat) / (1 + exp(mu.hat))
```

- Is it correct?
- What is the value of `sd` when generating `mu.hat`?
- Is there a better way?

Comment: Your simulation appears to have nothing to do with proportions at all. A "proportion," by definition, will be a count of a subset divided by the count of the set. You're not going to simulate counts by means of random normal variates! Ultimately, your question is not well posed because you need to tell us *what distribution* you want to use to generate values of $\pi$. Logistic? Beta? Binomial? Something else? If you're not sure, then change your question and tell us *why* you want do to this. What is your real objective?

Answer (score 1):

The below R code generates `n.sim` sample proportions from a binomial distribution where $n=$ `binom.n` and $p$ = `pi`.

```
rbinom(n = n.sim,  size = binom.n, p = pi)/binom.n
```